# ant: how to compare contents of two files

Tags: ant

I want to compare the contents of two files (say file1.txt,file2.txt) using ANT.

if files content are same then it should set some 'property' to true, if contents are not same then it should set the 'property' as false.

Can anyone suggest me any ANT task that can do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

You can use something like:

```
<condition property="property" value="true">
  <filesmatch file1="file1"
              file2="file2"/>
</condition>
```

This will set the property only if the files are the same.
You can then check for the property, using

```
<target name="foo" if="property">
...
</target>
```

This is available in ant, with no added dependency, see [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) for other conditions.

Comment: After doing condition task I want to do some stuff like printing the value of **property**. if files are same then it should print **true** and if not it should print **false** but for me it is only printing **false** even if files are same. `  <target name="main">
    <condition property="myproperty" value="true" else = "false">
 <filesmatch file1="file1" file2="file2"/>
    </condition>
    <echo message="myproperty = ${myproperty}"/>
  </target> `

Comment: I can't get that working and it drives me nuts! For some odd reason the filesmatch-task in my script always returns "false" except when file1 and file2 point to the very same file. But as soon as I point to different files (even if one is a 1:1 copy of the other) the value is false. Any idea why that could be so? This is on Windows 10 using ant version 1.8.2

Comment: Not sure what is causing our problem. It may be a misuse f the property in your build file, causing the condition property to be set before the actual condition is evaluated. Here is a very simple sample: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/26ae4ca184fd891b7401c0fb3585087d . It will print true if both files are identical, and nothing otherwise.

Comment: If the property isn't set to true, you can nevertheless make it false by adding 

<!-- otherwise --><property name="property " value="false"/>

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation to compare two files and switch into different targets depending on files match or files mismatch...

Heres the code:

```
<project name="prospector" basedir="../" default="main">

<!-- set global properties for this build -->
<property name="oldVersion" value="/code/temp/project/application/configs/version.ini"></property>
<property name="newVersion" value="/var/www/html/prospector/application/configs/version.ini"></property>

<target name="main" depends="prepare, runWithoutDeployment, startDeployment">
    <echo message="version match ${matchingVersions}"></echo>
    <echo message="version mismatch ${nonMatchingVersion}"></echo>
</target>

<target name="prepare">

    <!-- gets true, if files are matching -->
    <condition property="matchingVersions" value="true" else="false">
        <filesmatch file1="${oldVersion}" file2="${newVersion}" textfile="true"/>
    </condition>

    <!-- gets true, if files are mismatching -->
    <condition property="nonMatchingVersion" value="true" else="false">
        <not>
            <filesmatch file1="${oldVersion}" file2="${newVersion}" textfile="true"/>
        </not>
    </condition>

</target>

<!-- does not get into it.... -->
<target name="startDeployment" if="nonMatchingVersions">
    <echo message="Version has changed, update gets started..."></echo>
</target>

<target name="runWithoutDeployment" if="matchingVersions">
    <echo message="Version equals, no need for an update..."></echo>
</target>
```

The properties are correct and change on changing file contents. 
the task for nonMatchingVersions never gets started.