# Ant task to compare two properties files

Tags: java, ant, file-comparison

Does anyone know of an Ant task that would compare two (Java) properties files? I could not find any but I would like to be sure before I go off and implement it.

- **Input**: two properties files
- **Output**: list of property keys that are in one file but not in the other.

Just to be clear: it should perform properties-file-syntax-aware comparison, comparing the existence of keys, but ignoring the values.

Comment: Similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282542/ant-how-to-compare-contents-of-two-files

Comment: Not really, I'm interested in content-aware comparison. Meaning that it should compare the existence of keys, but ignore the values. Updated the question also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to combine a [groovy ant task](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) with the [java-diff-utils](http://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/wiki/SampleUsage) library

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── file1.properties
└── file2.properties
```

Running the build produces the following output:

```
diff:
   [groovy] [DeleteDelta, position: 1, lines: [two=2]]
   [groovy] [InsertDelta, position: 3, lines: [threeandhalf=3.5]]
   [groovy] [ChangeDelta, position: 4, lines: [five=5] to [five=55555]]
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="diff" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve">
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path">
            <dependency org="org.codehaus.groovy" name="groovy-all" rev="2.1.0-rc-1" conf="default"/>
            <dependency org="com.googlecode.java-diff-utils" name="diffutils" rev="1.2.1" conf="default"/>
        </ivy:cachepath>
    </target>

    <target name="diff" depends="resolve">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

        <groovy>
            import difflib.*

            def original = new File("file1.properties").readLines()
            def revised  = new File("file2.properties").readLines()

            Patch patch = DiffUtils.diff(original, revised)

            patch.getDeltas().each {
                println it
            }
        </groovy>
    </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- Uses [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to download dependencies

### file1.properties

```
one=1
two=2
three=3
four=4
five=5
```

### file2.properties

```
one=1
three=3
threeandhalf=3.5
four=4
five=55555
```

## Revised Example

Returns the properties in the first file missing in the second:

```
diff:
   [groovy] Missing keys: [two]
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="diff" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve">
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path">
            <dependency org="org.codehaus.groovy" name="groovy-all" rev="2.1.0-rc-1" conf="default"/>
        </ivy:cachepath>
    </target>

    <target name="diff" depends="resolve">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

        <groovy>
            def source = new Properties()
            def target = new Properties()

            new File("file1.properties").withInputStream { source.load(it) }
            new File("file2.properties").withInputStream { target.load(it) }

            def diff = source.findResults { k,v ->
                k in target ? null : k
            }

            println "Missing keys: ${diff}"
        </groovy>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. While it is good for just comparing text files, it is not the answer I was looking for. I'm interested in content-aware comparison. Meaning that it should compare the existence of keys, but ignore the values. I updated the question also. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @NeemePraks I've created a second example to find the missing keys.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Although I would prefer a full-blown Ant task, this will suffice for now.

Comment: @NeemePraks Nothing stopping you from writing your own custom task. Personally I find it simpler to embed Groovy scripts. It's immediate, simpler to change and groovy integrates very well with ANT.

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to use [PropDiff](http://www.baclace.net/java/prop_diff/) utility. It has options to compare, combine and intersect Java Properties files. It's open source, so you can modify it according to your requirements.

Here is the [documentation](http://www.baclace.net/java/prop_diff/PropDiff.html) for PropDiff.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that only requires the ant-contrib library:

```xml
<target name="checkPropertyFiles">
    <antcall target="ensureTwoFilesHaveSameProperties">
        <param name="file1" value="file1.properties"/>
        <param name="file2" value="file2.properties"/>
    </antcall>
</target>

<target name="ensureTwoFilesHaveSameProperties">
    <loadproperties srcFile="${file1}" prefix="prefixfile1"/>
    <loadproperties srcFile="${file2}" prefix="prefixfile2"/>

    <propertyselector property="file1.list" delimiter="," match="prefixfile1\.(.+)" select="\1"/>
    <propertyselector property="file2.list" delimiter="," match="prefixfile2\.(.+)" select="\1"/>

    <for list="${file1.list}" param="file1.property">
        <sequential>
            <if>
                <not>
                    <matches pattern=",@{file1.property}," string=",${file2.list}," />
                </not>
                <then>
                    <property name="error.encountered" value="true"/>
                    <echo message="Property @{file1.property} is present in ${file1} but not in ${file2}"/>
                </then>
            </if>
        </sequential>
    </for>
    <for list="${file2.list}" param="file2.property">
        <sequential>
            <if>
                <not>
                    <matches pattern=",@{file2.property}," string=",${file1.list}," />
                </not>
                <then>
                    <property name="error.encountered" value="true"/>
                    <echo message="Property @{file2.property} is present in ${file2} but not in ${file1}"/>
                </then>
            </if>
        </sequential>
    </for>

    <fail message="Property files do not have the same set of keys.">
        <condition>
            <isset property="error.encountered"/>
        </condition>
    </fail>

    <echo message="OK: ${file1} has same properties as ${file2}"/>
</target>
```