# how to diff files using Ant like the diff command -u on Linux

Tags: ant, groovy, diff

Background: 
Now I write some scripts to output the differences between two files into a file. Now I using Linux command diff -u.
Is there a way in Ant to diff files?
So that I can use groovy + ant + diff, and need not to invoke the local command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ant task to compare two properties files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381660/ant-task-to-compare-two-properties-files)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no diff command in ant.

You could just grab something [like java-diff-utils](https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/) and write your own though (if you want to avoid the system diff command)

```
@Grab('com.googlecode.java-diff-utils:diffutils:1.2.1')
import difflib.*

def fileAContents = '''Line 1
                      |Line 2
                      |Line 3'''.stripMargin().split( '\n' ).toList()

def fileBContents = '''Line 1
                      |Line Two
                      |Line 3'''.stripMargin().split( '\n' ).toList()

DiffUtils.diff( fileAContents, fileBContents ).deltas.each {
    println it
}
```

which prints:

```
[ChangeDelta, position: 1, lines: [Line 2] to [Line Two]]
```